# How do you make it a new object after extruding?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, faces

I just extrude faces from a mesh, now I need it to be a new object and not be a plane inside another object....

Comment: Press **P**-->Selection.

Comment: Appears @ikiste3D and I were commenting/answering at precisely the same time, ha ha.  I've deleted my comment here.

Answer (score 3):

Select the new faces you've created, hit <kbd>P</kbd>, then *Selected* and tap <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get out of *Edit Mode*. You'll be able to select the faces as another object now (its good to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on *Edit Mode inside the new object to correct the normals too)

Comment: How do you close the hole in the spot where you extruded?